# How can I check which method of checking a port state is more efficient?

Tags: perl, unix, tcp, port, perl-module

I'm writing a script to schedule port checks on some of my servers, and report the state. I am planning to go along with one of two options:

1. Pipe the output of netcat (nc) into a perl variable, and check the return state

   ```
   my $rcode=`nc -z 6.6.6.6 80; echo $?`
   ```
2. Use the perl module IO::Socket::PortState to do the same thing.

   ```
   use IO::Socket::PortState qw(check_ports);
   my %porthash = ( ... );
   check_ports($host,$timeout,\%porthash);
   print "$proto $_ is not open ($porthash{$proto}->{$_}->{name})
       if !$porthash{$proto}->{$_}->{open};
   ```

I'd like to go along the more efficient (shorter time, more specific) route.

Is there a rule of thumb regarding this? As in piping the output of a system command/unix utility is more/less efficient than using a perl module? Or are different perl modules different, and one can check the same only by setting up multiple iterations of these checks and compare the time taken by this versus a system call to execute a unix utility?

Comment: Yes. The rule of thumb is to benchmark it.

Comment: Benchmark -- definitely. I'd only add that you should be explicit about what you mean by "efficient".

Comment: I meant time efficient and precise (less false values).

Comment: you might consider use Socket; directly.  as this is the baseline socket implementation from perl, and a near direct mapping from c it should be the best means of doing this in perl.  Though tbh you could probably just as easily write it in C at this point, Socket.pm is that close to socket.h

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't really an answer to your question so much as a suggested implementation.

Just a quick run at an untested example of using Socket.pm.

This is probably the fastest perl implementation.  But at the point you are using socket.pm you may as well just write it in C with socket.h.  They are a near 1:1 mapping.

Ref:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use Socket;

$remote  = $ARGV[0];
$port    = $ARGV[1];

print ":: Attempting to connect to - $remote.\n";
$iaddr = inet_aton($remote) or die "Error: $!";
$paddr = sockaddr_in($port, $iaddr) or die "Error: $!";
$proto = getprotobyname('tcp') or die "Error: $!";

socket(SOCK, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, $proto) or die "Error: $!";
connect(SOCK, $paddr) or die "Error: $!";

print ":: Connected Successfully!\n";
```